# Loading lua script files in redis

Tags: lua, redis, servicestack

Could someone give an example of how to load and execute .lua script files in windows. I am using ServiceStack redis to loadluascript. It works to certain scripts which don't have module(...) like things.

I am getting this error

```
Error compiling script (new function): user_script:5: cannot use '...' outside a 
vararg function near '...' , sPort: 61688, LastCommand:
```

Any help by giving an example would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the above kind Lua script is to prepend local before a function or all variables. I took out the module thing and tweaked the Lua script to make it work. Later I realized the script will not be any use to me :). Thanks for looking into this post.

Comment: Yup, that sounds correct. Global scope is prohibited in redis-lua. Thx for the follow up.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted the Lua script you are trying to load or execute.

Three dots don't have anything to do with modules:

```
Vararg expressions, denoted by three dots ('...'), can only be used 
when directly inside a vararg function
```

I guess this answers your question: your Lua code is simply invalid.

Speaking of modules: you can't load your own modules in Redis Lua, which you might already know. See http://redis.io [Scripting](http://redis.io/commands/eval).

Comment: I am trying to load this module https://github.com/JakSprats/Alchemy-Database/blob/master/redis_unstable/src/core/Queue.lua into redis

Comment: Aha. The Lua script you are trying to load comes from AlchemyDB, which is based on a fork of redis-unstable of about three years back. This has nothing to do (according to my knowledge) with the current *native* Lua implementation of Redis itself. Maybe some ideas were exchanged (years back), but you are mixing the apples with the pears.